Is it possible to join a dataframe to a geographical shapefile?
I have two files in R (f1, f2) that have names of countries (each country only appears once in each file). I want to perform a join on both files using an inner join, and then the rows that don't match, I would use a fuzzy join to approximately match them.
Here is my approach: First I standardize all names (e.g. make all letters capital, remove spaces, commas, hyphens, apostrophes etc) - then I do an inner join to get exact matches. Then, on the names that don't match, I use a fuzzy match metric and join if the threshold is less than some constant:
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(stringdist)
library(stringr)


set.seed(123)

f1 <- data.frame(
  country = c("United States", "United Kingdom", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Spain", "Canada", "Japan", "Australia", "Brazil"),
  value1 = runif(10, 1, 100), value2 = runif(10, 1, 100), value3 = runif(10, 1, 100)
)

f2 <- data.frame(
  country = c("United States of America", "United Kingdom", "French Republic", "Germany", "Italian Republic", "Kingdom of Spain", "Canada", "Japan", "Commonwealth of Australia", "Federative Republic of Brazil"),
  value2 = runif(10, 1, 100)
)

standardize_name <- function(name) {
    name %>%
        str_to_upper() %>%
        str_replace_all("[[:punct:]]", "") %>%
        str_replace_all("\\s+", "")
}

f1 <- f1 %>%
    mutate(country_std = standardize_name(country))

f2 <- f2 %>%
    mutate(country_std = standardize_name(country))

inner_joined <- inner_join(f1, f2, by = "country")

unmatched_f1 <- anti_join(f1, f2, by = "country")
unmatched_f2 <- anti_join(f2, f1, by = "country")

fuzzy_joined <- stringdist_join(unmatched_f1, unmatched_f2,
                                by = "country",
                                mode = "left",
                                method = "lv",
                                max_dist = 5,
                                distance_col = "distance")

final_result <- bind_rows(inner_joined, fuzzy_joined)

However, in reality, f2 is not a data frame, but a shapefile (https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/  : Admin 0 – Countries). I am not sure if fuzzy matches can be used when one file is a shapefile and the other is data frame.
Does anyone know if this is possible? The final result should be a sf object for plotting, have all columns from f1, and should have all rows from f2.
Cheers

Yes, if you read the shapefile using sf::st_read then you can treat it just like an ordinary dataframe (it has an extra list column with the shapefile coordinate information).

Thank you .. could you please show me how to do this if you have time?

Yes, after converting a SpatVector to an sf object, you can join it to a data frame, on the region column. For example,
library(geodata)
library(sf)

w <- world(path=tempdir())

geodata_joined <- st_as_sf(w) %>%
    right_join(external_data,
        by = join_by(NAME_0 == country))

Please look at the CRAN Spatial Task View.
